# How to create Array of Pointers in Java ? Below is code in c as an example , and for my project JAVA is compulsory , so can you help me out?

Tags: java, c, arrays, pointers

Author : Daman Jha
    //Example in c . How to write this code in JAVA ?//

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX = 3;

int main ()
{
 int  var[] = {10, 100, 200};
 int i, *ptr[MAX];  //here is array of pointers in c ,  How can I use
                   // this facility in JAVA?

 for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
  ptr[i] = &var[i]; /* assign the address of integer. */
}
for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
      printf("Value of var[%d] = %d\n", i, *ptr[i] );
}
return 0;
}
```

//////Thank you

Comment: You cannot use "pointers" in Java - this concept is missing from the language.

Comment: @stark To a Java `int`, there's not even a reference. A Java `Integer` variable (like any other variable of some object type) holds a "reference" to an object, and there's no other way. So you can't say "use references", because either there are none, or there is nothing else. ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op forgets there is a lot of book about java that he or she can read and stackoverflow is not conversion coding service.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like an array of `Object`

Comment: That C example simply isn't useful/applicable to Java.

Answer (score 4):

In Java you handle *references* on objects. You also have some native types like `int`, `float`, `long`, etc. that are *values*. When you pass parameters to methods, either object references or native type values are always passed *by value* - there is no deep-copy stuff involved or *passed by reference*. See [Passed By Value Damnit!](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) for a quick comparison between C/Pascal/Java.

To translate your exemple and have an array of *references* on integers that are contains in another array, you can use `Integer` objects, e.g.

```
Integer[] foo = {1,2,3,4};
Integer[] bar = new Integer[foo.length];
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
   bar[i] = foo[i]; // bar[i] and foo[i] reference the same Integer object
}
```

Note that `Integer` class is immutable. It means that even if you have a reference on an element of `foo` through `bar`, you cannot modify the element itself. `Integer` class does not provide methods that can modify an object value (in C, you can do `*ptr[1] = 123` and it will actually modify `var[1]`).

Comment: Although this approach isn't wrong, it doesn't achieve anything useful. Since the `Integer`s are immutable, it will give the same behavior here as using `int`. The real answer is that OP should not be trying to apply a C tutorial to Java in the first place.

Comment: Fully agree with you - see my ending note. And to go further, the OP should explain the **actual** problem he is trying to solve, since his example doesn't do much.